# Regex, I want to select (word + anything + word)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to select `name="custom-custom-selected"`
and this is my regex `\w*(name=".*-selected)`

What I'm trying to say is that I want to select every word starting wtih "name=" and ending with "-selected" and has anything in between (digits or letters)

How do i say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
name="(.*?)-selected"
```

`*?` is a lazy quantifier, it means it will eat up as little as possible (so that `.*` doesn't select `custom-custom-selected"name="custom-custom` in `name="custom-custom-selected"name="custom-custom-selected"`)

The result is in the first capturing group.

Comment: @Barney: Technically he asked for a word starting with `name=` ending with `selected`, so it would be the whole match... It's true he probably wants what's inside the quotes, so he can either add `-selected` to the result or use `name="(.*?-selected)"` indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you(using greedy). If you want you can make it non-greed using `.*?`:

```
name="(.*)-selected"
```

If you want to catch only a certain characters, then use this:

```
name="([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-selected"
```

Comment: And to capture the entire hyphenated attribute, as the OP asked, would require `name="((.*?)-selected)"`.

Comment: Remember that you don't need to escape `-` in a character class when it's the last of first element inside it.

Comment: @Robin thanks. I know. OP is new to regex. So I escaped it. So that they don't mess it up when placing any other characters after the `-` :-)

Comment: @SabujHassan: yeah, I know you know :) I see your point, I'll leave the info in the comment so that it's still somewhere near (subliminally speaking)